# R data frame: convert all data frame elements from characters to numerics while keeping decimals

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
   V1      V2     V3      V4       V5   V6
1:  1 0.007d0 0.73d0 4.165d0 1438.8d0 6050
```

The `d` notation is alike to scientific notation.

THe problem here is that when I read the numbers with these ds into R, R treat them as characters instead of numerics. Is there a way to read the table in and change all the elements to numeric, all the while preserving the decimals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like below?

```
df[] <- lapply(
  df,
  function(x) {
    eval(str2lang(gsub("d","e",x)))
  }
)
```

and you will see

```
> df
  V1    V2   V3    V4     V5   V6
1  1 0.007 0.73 4.165 1438.8 6050

> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ V1: num 1
 $ V2: num 0.007
 $ V3: num 0.73
 $ V4: num 4.16
 $ V5: num 1439
 $ V6: num 6050
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = 1L, V2 = "0.007d0", V3 = "0.73d0", V4 = "4.165d0",
    V5 = "1438.8d0", V6 = 6050L), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```

Comment: Or another way is `df[] <- type.convert(lapply(df, chartr, old = 'd', new = 'e'), as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot. This is cool. I learnt a new function `chartr` :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

DF %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(str_replace(., "d(?=\\d+)", "e"))))

  V1    V2   V3    V4     V5   V6
1  1 0.007 0.73 4.165 1438.8 6050
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_remove` to remove pattern and convert to numeric using mutate

```
library("dplyr")
library("stringr")


df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(str_remove(.,"d"))))
```

Comment: Never mind. A smilar answer was already posted.  But this works as well